# editar y agregar productos CRUDbooster

Tags: php, laravel-6

Soy nuevo utilizando el plugin de laravel que se llama **Crudbooster**, que por cierto es bastante bueno y simplifica muchas acciones. sin embargo recientemente comencé a utilizar la herramienta para poder tener control sobre mis productos en la base de datos (previamente ya creados), que son aproximadamente 18 millones de registros. todo normal

Cree un modulo en la opción `Module Generator -> add new module`
hasta ahora todo perfecto, se habilito un modulo en el panel del admin
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso, busca un producto de manera correcta.

lo que estoy viendo es ahora como darle uso a los botones de acciones

Detail Data
Edit data

cuando los presiono, no carga ninguna información ni campos,

cree un modelo con `php artisan make:migrate create_products --create=products`
y agregue unos cuantos campos, pero eso no se ve reflejado ni muestra los datos.

¿Quizás puedan guiarme en esto? y como puedo hacer que los datos carguen respectivamente.

Comment: deberías de fijarte en la información que tiene en la creación de modulos, hay unas partes donde dice lo de la tabla que se muestra y otro donde está la información con la que se relaciona en la BD, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: @MauEspaña si tienes toda la razon, comence a estudiar bien la documentacion y crear una base solida, en este entonces recientemente estaba conociendo la herramienta, muchas gracias por responder, saludos